# MVC Controller Not Getting Hit

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I can't get my Controller action method to get hit when I click 'Detail View' tab, or any tab for that matter.  However, I can get the action method to hit if I comment out `return false;` in the javascript section, but then my 'Selected' tab is not maintained.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.test').click(function () {            
        $('.test').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        return false;
    });
});    
</script>    

<div id="tabs" class="shadetabs">
    <ul>
        <li class="test selected">@Html.ActionLink("Overview", "Index", "Statistics")</li> 
        <li class="test">@Html.ActionLink("Detail View", "Detail", "Statistics")</li>  
        <li class="test">@Html.ActionLink("Trends", "Trends", "Statistics")</li>                
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Should class="test selected" be class="selected" ?

Comment: @DerekBeattie: Why does it matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By returning false you are canceling the default link action which is to send a request to your controller action. So if you do this you will need to manually send a request (AJAX?) and use the results from this request to modify the DOM. For example:

```
$('.test').click(function () {            
    $('.test').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        success: function(result) {
            // TODO: do something with the result here
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Or you could do this without any javascript.

So for example you could write a [custom HTML helper](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs) that will generate this menu:

```
public static MvcHtmlString MenuLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
    string linkText, 
    string actionName, 
    string controllerName
)
{
    var routeData = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData;
    string currentAction = routeData.GetRequiredString("action");
    string currentController = routeData.GetRequiredString("controller");
    if (actionName == currentAction && controllerName == currentController)
    {
        return htmlHelper.ActionLink(
            linkText,
            actionName,
            controllerName,
            null,
            new {
                @class = "selected"
            }
        );
    }
    return htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName);
}
```

and then simply:

```
<ul>
  <li>@Html.MenuLink("Overview", "Index", "Statistics")</li>
  <li>@Html.MenuLink("Detail View", "Detail", "Statistics")</li>
  <li>@Html.MenuLink("Trends", "Trends", "Statistics")</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The click event handler are on the `<li>` and not on the links. You mean that the javascript engine propagates the click from the root node down to the clicked node?

Comment: I have one issue...the class='selected' is on the link and not the li, so the tab is not actually selected. Do you know how to have the class='selected' on the <li> and not the link(<a>)?

Answer (score 0):

The code was good. But i think try to make **li** tag with unique id.